# Fuzzy logic application

Tags: logic

I have to establish the probability that a patient has covid, based on three factors: -number of symptoms -number of close contacts with positive people -number of contacts NOT close with positive people
Assuming I know these numbers, for example patient has 3 symptoms, 2 close contacts and 1 not close.
What I did was establish individual probabilities for those three factors, for example:
0 symptoms prob 0;
1 symptoms prob 0.2;
2 symptoms prob 0.35 ...
Similar for close and non-close contacts......
Once this was done, I used a weighted average: SumWeights = S + C + C1, where these three values ​​are respectively the individual probabilities of symptoms, close and non-close contacts (e.g. if the patient has 1 symptom, S will be 0.2). Then I normalized the weights, dividing S,C and C1 by SumWeights Finally I calculated Prob= (SymptomNumber*Snormalized + NumberStrictConts*Cnormalized + NumberNonStrictCounts*C1normalized) However, strange values ​​come out, even higher than 1 (in fuzzy logic I should have values ​​between 0 and 1). How can I modify?

Comment: why do you think fuzzy logic is applicable here? You are tying to compute the probability of having COVID conditioned on three factors: # of symptoms, # of close contacts with positive people, and # of NOT close contacts with positive people. You can utilize Baye's Rule for this.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy Hi, honestly I wouldn't apply it, but it's a project for my university (I'm developing a program) and the teacher told me to use fuzzy logic (don't ask me why xD). That's why I was wondering how I can use it,

Comment: if you have real world data, then I suggest taking another approach such as developing a logistic regression model or a Bayesian network. This will capture interactions between variables that are not accounted for by a weighted average.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy yes I guess I'll use bayesian network. I take my data from India, so a real dataset and an ontology based on covid. I don't think fuzzy logic is so OK for this exercise

Comment: On a separate note, I can see at least one serious probelm with the probabilities you calculated. It is NOT true that the probability of having COVID given zero symptoms is $0$. This is because people may be infected but *not yet* displaying symptoms (because they are in the incubation stage), or they may be infected and be asymptomatic carriers of the disease. However, if you accumulate a sufficient amount of representative data and utilize an appropriate model, such as a Bayesian network, then this will correct itself.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy oh yep, I had to fix that point too. Thank you for reminding me xD

Comment: Concerning your mathematical issue: It looks like you calculated $$\frac{n_SS + n_CC+n_{C_1}C_1}{S + C + C_1}.$$ where each of the multipliers $n_S, n_C, n_{C_1}$ are counts. If each of those counts $\ge 1$, of course the result will be $\ge 1$. I'm not sure how this is supposed to relate to fuzzy sets, but it is clearly not the right equation.

Comment: @PaulSinclair yes I messed up. I'm now using Bayes, calculating P(A| B, C, D), where B, C, D are those three factors